# django cannot connect to the database on the server

Tags: django, database, postgresql, deployment, vps

I have deployed the project and an error occurred Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

```
`System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

````
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 574, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied```
````

in the file .env seems to have indicated everything correctly, and everything seems to be fine in postgresql, the database is there, the user is there and the password is correct, I'm already tired of sitting with it

changed the user's password in postgresql, and changed the user in .env

Comment: Share yoir related Django settings. Are you reading your env variables correctly?

Comment: Have you set at `settings.py` at `DATABASES={'default': {..., 'PASSWORD': 'db_password'}}` ?

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('NAME_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('USER_DB'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('PASSWORD_DB'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('PORT_DB'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('HOST'),
    }
}
here are my settings, if you need certain settings, you can tell me more precisely what settings are needed, or should I throw off the whole settings.py ?